# Another SQL-Interrogation

Tags: mysql, sql, select, oracle10g

I've got another problem on my SQL Tables but this time I've got more tables linked together.
What I realised and where I'm stuck:

I have tables about jobs, wages, employees.

I've done a query with these conditions:

The employee with the biggest wage in my company:

```
select employee_id, count(employee) as  wage 
from number_statistics 
group by employee_id 
having count(employee_id) in 
(select max(count(employee_id)) from number_statistics group by employee_id);
```

This will show the ID of my employee with the biggest wage.

Where I'm stuck:

My next task is to create this query:

I need to display the employee with the biggest wage on three age categories:
Between 21-30; 30-45; 45-60;

The problem is that I don't have a field name AGE (and I'm not allowed to use one) in my tables.
I only have the birth date of my employees.

Comment: You say you've got three tables, but your example query uses a fourth.  It isn't obvious why `COUNT(employee)` would give you a wage.  I think you need to clarify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the fully answer to this, I think your solution involves the function

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,curdate()) BETWEEN 21 AND 30
```

This returns results that have between 21 and 30 years.